# how to put image to jEditable placeholder?

Tags: c#, .net, image, placeholder, jeditable

Image in place-holder displays, but when I click on it - got some `<img/>` tag in  jEditable  input.
Anyone knows how to remove it ?

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#Video3').editable(function (value, settings) {
        companyName(value, "Video3");
        return value;
    },
        {
            cancel: 'Cancel',
            submit: 'OK',
            style: 'inherit',
            tooltip: 'Add video',
            placeholder: '<img class="placeholder"  alt="edit" src="/UserControlsAdmin/ExhibitorZone/img/Add_Video.png" />"
            });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've checked the [source code](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable/jquery.jeditable.js) , [line 167](https://github.com/tuupola/jquery_jeditable/blob/master/jquery.jeditable.js#L167) removes the placeholder's content if it is equal to `settings.placeholder`

```
/* Remove placeholder text, replace is here because of IE. */
if ($(this).html().toLowerCase().replace(/(;|"|\/)/g, '') == settings.placeholder.toLowerCase().replace(/(;|"|\/)/g, ''))
{
    $(this).html('');
}
```

you can add this code after that if you want to remove the img tag

```
if ($(this).html().toLowerCase().indexOf('img') > -1)
{
     $(this).html('');
}
```

Comment: thank you! You saved my day :) ps cant + you answer my reputation is low ))